# Session conflict for frontend and backend logins - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a site which has a front end and a backend section.
The problem is, when I login from the frontend section, and open the admin dashboard, I am logged in automatically, I dont want admin to login unless he enters the username and password.

I am using sessions.

How will I be able to fix that.. ? I am using codeigniter

Comment: Create 2 different session for user and admin .

Comment: can it be done using the same session ..? bcs ill have to change the code .. is der any other way

Comment: you can also create session with user-type which differentiate both user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With out seeing your code it bit hard but here is how I do front and back end

Config.php

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);

$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';

if ($segments[2] == 'admin') {

    $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'admin_sessions';
    $config['sess_expiration'] = 1440;
    $config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/cache/session/admin/';

} else {

    $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'catalog_sessions';
    $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
    $config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/cache/session/catalog/';

}

$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

Another way to set

```
$data = array(
    'is_logged' => true,
    'user_id' => somenumber
);

$this->session->set_userdata('backend', $data);


$data1 = array(
    'is_logged' => true,
    'customer_id' => somenumber
);

$this->session->set_userdata('frontend', $data1);
```

Accessing

```
$admin_session_data = $this->session->userdata('backend');

echo $admin_session_data['user_id'];

$frontend_session_data = $this->session->userdata('frontend');

echo $frontend_session_data['customer_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

simple Differentiate the user by setting session variable

set session for user

```
$_SESSION['user']['username'];
```

set session for admin panel

```
$_SESSION['admin']['username'];
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks wolfgang.

for those who have subdirectory to host CI you can use the following method,

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){
    $protocol = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "off") ? "https" : "http";
}else{
    $protocol = 'http';
}

$actual_link = $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = str_replace($config['base_url'], '', $actual_link);

$segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);

$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';

if ($segments[0] == 'admin') {

    $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'admin_sessions';
    $config['sess_expiration'] = 1440;
    $config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 
    'application/cache/session/admin/';

} else {

    $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'catalog_sessions';
    $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
    $config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 
    'application/cache/session/catalog/';

}

$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```